# driver.find_element_by_css_selector running slow toward end of page

Tags: python, driver

I have a `from selenium import webdriver` temperature web scraper working from [weather.com](https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USPA1290:1:US) using Python. The web scraper at the beginning of the page finds the correct high and low temperature almost instantly. However, toward the end of the page, it gets increasingly slower (takes 7 seconds toward the end). This is probably because the scraper has to go through more HTML to find the correct data(?). Here is the main part of the code:

```
high = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(j) + ') > td.temp > div > span:nth-child(1)').text
low = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(j) + ') > td.temp > div > span:nth-child(3)').text
    date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(j) + ') > td:nth-child(2) > div > span').text

#auth > div > div > div > div > div > form > button

#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div > span
#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div > span
```

Is there an easy (or complex) fix to this? And if you think there is no easy solution, that would be great help too (which could be the case?)

Comment: How big is the page?  Seven seconds seems awfully slow.  Is this code in a loop?

Comment: yes its looping through the biggest 30 cities in the United States.  for i in range(0,len(city_url)): 
        print(pd.Timestamp.today())
        driver.get(city_url[i]) #Go to the url for each city.
        print(city_url[i])
        print(pd.Timestamp.today()).

Answer (score 1):

Is any content that you're looking for generated by JavaScript? If it's only HTML you could avoid headless browser and use `requests` and `bs4`:

```
$ python test.py
Got response: 200
Today JUN 1  80°/61°
Sun   JUN 2  70°/47°
Mon   JUN 3  63°/45°
Tue   JUN 4  74°/57°
Wed   JUN 5  75°/64°
Thu   JUN 6  77°/63°
Fri   JUN 7  77°/64°
Sat   JUN 8  81°/66°
Sun   JUN 9  81°/65°
Mon   JUN 10 80°/63°
Tue   JUN 11 80°/63°
Wed   JUN 12 81°/62°
Thu   JUN 13 80°/63°
Fri   JUN 14 81°/63°
Sat   JUN 15 81°/63°
Total: 0.66s, request: 0.60s
```

**test.py**

```
import requests
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USPA1290:1:US'


def fetch(url):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get(URL, timeout=5)
        return r


def main():
    start_t = time.time()
    resp = fetch(URL)
    print(f'Got response: {resp.status_code}')
    html = resp.text
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tds = bs.find_all('td', class_='twc-sticky-col', attrs={'headers': 'day'})
    for td in tds:
        date_time = td.find_next('span', class_='date-time')
        day_detail = td.find_next('span', class_='day-detail')
        temp = td.find_next('td', class_='temp', attrs={'headers': 'hi-lo'})
        hi_lo = '/'.join(i.text for i in temp.find_all('span', class_=''))
        print(f'{date_time.text:5} {day_detail.text:6} {hi_lo}')
    end_t = time.time()
    elapsed_t = end_t - start_t
    r_time = resp.elapsed.total_seconds()
    print(f'Total: {elapsed_t:.2f}s, request: {r_time:.2f}s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```